# Android application without an actual process running the app

Tags: android

I was reading ["Multitasking the Android Way"](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html) by Dianne Hackborn and found one sentence I don't quite understand (I bolded the puzzling part):

> A common misunderstanding about Android multitasking is the difference
>   between a process and an application. In Android these are not tightly
>   coupled entities: **applications may seem present to the user without an
>   actual process currently running the app**; multiple applications may
>   share processes, or one application may make use of multiple processes
>   depending on its needs; the process(es) of an application may be kept
>   around by Android even when that application is not actively doing
>   something.

How is it even possible? To "present" an application to the user, we need a least one of its activities to be in resumed state, and for this we need the underlying Linux process up and running, right? Is she talking about the application launcher or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To "present" an application to the user, we need a least one of its activities to be in resumed state, and for this we need the underlying Linux process up and running, right?

There are a few ways in which the user can see an app's UI without the app having a currently running process, such as:

- The app can have an app widget on the home screen
- The app can have a `Notification` in the status bar, or on a Wear device
- The app can have an entry in the recent-tasks list

My interpretation is that "applications may seem present" refers to something like these.